# python 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python, int, typeerror, callable

I am getting the python error "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable", which I understand to mean that I am accidentally putting parentheses directly after a variable or something like that, but I don't see that in my code. My code is

```
numFather = random.randrange(0, 10)
numMother = random.randrange = 10 - numFather
print numFather
print numMother
child = []
childgen = []
for FatherCounter in range(0, numFather):
    child.append(FatherTraits[random.randrange(0,5)])
for MotherCounter in range(0, numMother):
    child.append(MotherTraits[random.randrange(0,5)])
```

The error is at

```
child.append(FatherTraits[random.randrange(0,5)])
```

If I comment that out it happens again at

```
child.append(MotherTraits[random.randrange(0,5)])
```

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: What do you think this does - `random.randrange = 10 - numFather` ?

Comment: `numMother = random.randrange = 10 - numFather` this line sets random.randrange to an `int`. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: My guess is he wants `numMother = random.randrange(0, 10-numFather)`

Comment: Or maybe just `numMother = 10 - numFather`.

Answer (score 1):

Where you put

```
numMother = random.randrange = 10 - numFather
```

you have assigned the number `10 - numFather` to `random.randrange`. So `random.randrange` is now a number, rather than a function. Whatever you were trying to do, this is not it.

Comment: that's it. Stupid mistake: I put the wrong thing on that line and when I went back to fix it I accidentally left some of the original line

Answer (score 0):

I agree to @khelwood, random.randrange is being set to a integer value, but here are few other edits

The FatherTraits and MotherTraits, aren't defined. The code line `child.append(FatherTraits[random.randrange(0,5)])` is calling the FatherTraits's random number and appending it to child.

So by defining `FatherTraits` and `MotherTraits`, your code should work.

```
import random

numFather = random.randrange(0, 10)
numMother = 10 - numFather

child = []
childgen = []

FatherTraits = ['a','b','c','e','f','g']
MotherTraits = ['u','v','w','x','y','z']


for FatherCounter in range(0, numFather):
    child.append(FatherTraits[random.randrange(0,5)])
for MotherCounter in range(0, numMother):
    child.append(MotherTraits[random.randrange(0,5)])
```